# Pass prop from modal to Home screen

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-props

I am using React Native and React Native Modal.

What I would like to do is to enter task details (text) into modal and on HIDE modal click pass entered text to Home screen.

Tried to pass text as state property - not success though...

This is my Modal:

```
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    taskDetails: ''
  };
  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }    
  render() {
     const textInput = {
      backgroundColor: '#a2a2a2'
    }
    const styles = {
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 5,
      height: 50,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#fbfbfb',
      borderColor: '#a2a2a2',
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderStyle: 'solid'
    }
return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
           }}
          >
          <View>
            <View>  
              <View>
                <Text>Service name</Text>
                <TextInput style={textInput} onChangeText={taskDetails => this.setState({ taskDetails })} value={this.state.taskDetails} />
              </View>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: in the constructor:

 `this.state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    taskDetails: ''
  };`

Comment: Why do you have modalVisible marked once as false, and another time is visible?!

Answer (score 1):

IF your HomeScreen is another screen, you can pass your desired data through setParams from navigation prop, as said [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html):

```
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.setParams({ name: 'Lucy' })}
        title="Set title name to 'Lucy'"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

and then getting it from HomeScreen:

```
const name = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'Lucy');
```

BUT, if your HomeScreen is a parent for that component, you can pass onChangeText function as prop, and then setState or call other functions from there.